# Change Algorithm caption Label color to blue and bold italics

Tags: formatting, captions, algorithm2e

I wanted to know how to go about changing the algorithm caption label to blue and  bold italics.  I have so far been able to change the caption name to blue, but I have not been able to change the algorithm caption label to bold and italicized.  Here is the code that I have so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, amsthm, bm}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
\newcommand\mycommfont[1]{\footnotesize\ttfamily\textcolor{blue}{#1}}
\SetCommentSty{mycommfont}
\SetAlgoCaptionSeparator{.}
\renewcommand\AlCapFnt{\textit\textbf\color{blue}}
\usepackage[font={color=mybluei,bf,it},figurename=Fig.,labelfont={it}]{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\colorbox[gray]{0.95}{
\begin{minipage}{0.65\textwidth}
\SetAlgoLined
\SetNlSty{textbf}{}{:}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\DontPrintSemicolon
This is line one\\
This is line two numbered\\
This should be numbered\\
This should also be numbered
\caption{Unnumbered lines}
\end{algorithm} 
\end{minipage}} 
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe `\renewcommand\AlCapFnt{\itshape\bfseries\color{blue}}`?

Comment: @Benjamin, Thanks for your input.  The `\AlCapFnt`, appears to change the algorithm name, "Algorithm 1". I wanted to be able to change the caption name, so in this example, it will be to change "Unnumbered lines" to `\itshape\bfseries\color{blue}`.  I will change my original question to be clearer.  Thanks again for your help so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e)'s `\caption` has the following format:

```
\AlCapSty{\AlCapFnt Algorithm 1:}\AlCapNameSty{\AlCapNameFnt my algorithm}
```

Taken from the "change log":

> By default, `\AlCapSty` is `\textbf` and `\AlCapFnt` is nothing. `\AlCapNameSty` keep text as it is, and `\AlCapNameFnt` do nothing also.
>   You can redefine `\AlCapFnt` and `\AlCapNameFnt` by giving macro to `\Set...` commands. For example, you can do `\SetAlCapFnt{\large}` to see Algorithm printed in `\large` font.
>
> You can redefine `\AlCapSty`, `\AlCapFnt`, `\AlCapNameSty` and `\AlCapNameFnt` with the corresponding `\Set...` command. For the `\...Sty` commands, you have to give in parameter name of a macro (without `\`) which takes one argument. For example, `\SetAlCapFnt{textbf}` defines the default behaviour. If you want to do more complicated thing, you should define your own macro and give it to `\SetAlCapFnt` or `\SetAlCapNameFnt`. Here are two examples:
>
> ```
> \newcommand{\mycapsty}[1]{\tiny #1}\SetAlCapNameSty{mycapsty}
> \newcommand{\mycapsty}[1]{\textsl{\small #1}}\SetAlCapNameSty{mycapsty}
> ```
>
> Or you can combine the two, for the last example you can also do:
>
> ```
> \SetAlCapNameSty{textsl}\SetAlCapNameFnt{\small}
> ```

With the above information, the following provides what you're after:

```
\renewcommand\AlCapFnt{\itshape\bfseries\color{blue}}
\renewcommand\AlCapNameFnt{\AlCapFnt}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

% \AlCapSty{\AlCapFnt Algorithm 1:}\AlCapNameSty{\AlCapNameFnt my algorithm}
\renewcommand\AlCapFnt{\itshape\bfseries\color{blue}}
\renewcommand\AlCapNameFnt{\AlCapFnt}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \DontPrintSemicolon
  This is line one \;
  This is line two numbered \;
  This should be numbered \;
  This should also be numbered
  \caption{Unnumbered lines}
\end{algorithm} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: I am sorry for asking this, but I couldn't really comprehend the difference between `AlCapFnt` and `AlCapSty`. `AlCapFnt` can change the font name and size in addition to the ability of centering the caption. So, what is the need for `AlCapSty` or when do I need to redefine `AlCapSty`?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: The package author tried to keep a `f`o`nt`-specific switch for the `cap`tion in `\AlCapFnt`, while `\AlCapSty` is meant to represent the entire `cap`tion `sty`le. This could include font switches as well as other things (like fixed text). You don't have to use `\AlCapFnt`, as you can insert that manually as part of `\AlCapSty`.

Comment: When trying to change `AlCapSty`, I have to do it in this 2-command step: `\newcommand{\mycapsty}[1]{\centering\normalfont#1}
\SetAlCapNameSty{mycapsty}`. Is there a single command that can do the same job?

Comment: @DiaaAbidou: Yes, try `\renewcommand{\AlCapFnt}{\centering\normalfont}`.

Answer (score 2):

Change the `\caption` command line to `\caption{\color{blue}` `\textbf{\textit{Unnumbered lines}}}` and compile you will get:

[image: captionblue]

Comment: Thanks for your input.  I was looking for a way to automatically do it, just like the `\renewcommand\AlCapFnt{\itshape\bfseries\color{blue}}`.  You set it once in the preamble and then its set.  Do you know of a solution to set the caption label in the same manner so you would not have to always type `\caption{\color{blue} \textbf{\textit{` ?  Thanks.